# Post Data Using AngularJS to MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

My AngularJs Post Request on Service.js:

```
 this.Add = function (employee) {
         var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/Employee/Add",
            data: JSON.stringify(employee),
            dataType: "json",
        });
        return response;
    }
```

My Modal Class:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        { }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; } 
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; } 
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Add Method of EmployeeController:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public string Add(Employee employeeNew)
        {
                if (employeeNew != null)
                {
                    unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Insert(employeeNew);
                    unitOfWork.Save();
                    return "Record has been Added";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Record has Not been Verified";
                } 
        }
```

I use MVC 2.0. When I made the request above, Employee class on the Add method was empty. On the other hand, when i looked at my add request, i saw that request had FirstName, LastName,UserName and Password values with full of correct data. How could I bind these properties to Employee object of on Add method.

Comment: I had the same issue..but I switched from `.apsx` page `.cshtml` page. it resolved my issue, I know its not appropriate way to do it..but still this is workaroud

Answer (score 0):

$http is an asynchronous request. This means the return of this request consist of a promis, something you can do after the request finished and the method received the data. You have to handle this promis using callbacks. Try:

```
this.Add = function (employee) {
     var response = {}

 $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Employee/Add",
        data: JSON.stringify(employee),
        dataType: "json",
    }).succes(function(data){

      response = data;

    }).error(function(){

       //Handle errors caused by the HTTP-request

    })
}
```

Comment: I can do that but my problem is about binding the PostValues as an Employee class object. My angular controller file is like this.

$scope.Save = function () {
        var Employee = {
            FirstName: $scope.FirstName ,
            LastName: $scope.LastName ,
            UserName: $scope.UserName,
            Password: $scope.Password 
        }; var getMSG = angularService.Add(Employee);